# A Simple Riddle That Is Relatively Short

Tags: riddle

I have veins that hold no blood.
I dwarf the trees.
I grew once like a child,
but now I'm immortal.
Pluck my hair or cut my flesh,
I'll feel no pain.

**What am I?**

Comment: We've put your question on hold as "too broad", since there are too many possible answers which could fit the riddle as stated, Please [edit] to add some more lines and narrow down the possibilities, and we can get the question reopened again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could be a...

> **Mountain**

*I have veins that hold no blood.*

> Could be a [geological vein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vein_(geology)), such as gold or silver that is formed in the rocks.

*I dwarf the trees.*

> Most mountains are taller than most trees.

*I grew once like a child,*

> Some mountains are formed by rocks and earth that increase in size through various [tectonic process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mountain_formation). For example, volcanoes are often formed between tectonic plates.

*but now I'm immortal.*

> A mountain is not an organic creature. It does not "die".

*Pluck my hair or cut my flesh,*

> Possibly referring to removing plants that grow on a mountainside, or mining rocks from the mountain, or digging into it somehow.

*I'll feel no pain.*

> Because it is made of stone.

Also, the title "A Simple Riddle That Is Relatively Short"

> Relative to the height of a mountain, the riddle's length is very short!

Answer (score 2):

Are you a...

> River

I have veins that hold no blood.

> When viewed from above rivers and their offshoots can look like vein patterns.

I dwarf the trees.

> Rivers are generally bigger than trees.

I grew once like a child,
but now I'm immortal.

> Rivers are formed once and appear immortal.

Pluck my hair or cut my flesh,

> You can pull plants from a river or take its water.

I'll feel no pain.

> It's just water.

A Simple Riddle That Is Relatively Short

> Rivers can be described as *long*, hence this riddle is *relatively short*.

Answer (score 0):

(This is my first answer as a newbie- constructive comments about writing answers appreciated.)
:-)

I wondered if the answer could be

> "the Planet Earth".

*I have veins that hold no blood*

> As for the "Mountain" answer above, the Planet Earth has veins of minerals.

*I dwarf the trees*

> Planets generally dwarf trees.

*I grew once like a child*

> After the Big Bang, planets like Earth were coalescing balls of molten rock that grew bigger as their gravity attracted other small lumps of molten rock.

*But now I'm immortal.*

> To all practical intents and purposes, the planet Earth is immortal.

*Pluck my hair or cut my flesh, I'll feel no pain.*

> The Earth doesn't feel ploughs carving into it, or people cutting crops/trees etc.